# What kind of grass is this? KBG?

Tags: lawn, grass

Trying to figure out what this grass is, because I like it. Very soft. I've been cutting my grass @ 3.5" mower height so its seems to get quite matted. Depending on the grass type maybe that's too high. This picture is not just mowed, I mowed this law a week ago, but as I said, @ 3.5"

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think there's just one kind (species) of grass growing. I opened up your photos in a new window each and enlarging the image, I can see fine thin blades as well as wider blades.

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: I live in Massachusetts. It's definitely a mix of grasses. I will go closer up next time and look at the details of the blades. Thanks for the link pnuts!

Answer (score 3):

This is lovely grass!  But this is a bit long.  Did you really measure this length as 3.5"  Grins.  I adore grass that looks like this but this takes special maintenance practices to include being in partial shade and thus different fertilizers and application timing.

I can't believe this is 3.5 inches! 6" maybe!  And definitely a mixture of cool season grasses to include fescue and bluegrass.  You need to raise that mower as high as possible, 3.5" no lower and mow your grass asap.  When it begins to lay over other members in the crop you will get dead patches, fungus and irregularities.  I've only been able to do this in partial shade with fertilizer that is equal for N P and K.  Not higher in N as for normal lawns.  It only lasts a month or two like this and then it has to be mowed.  But this needs mowing now!  It is in the sun and that causes more growth than partial shade.

A great rotary mower creates a vacuum that pulls the grass blades up to be cut off equally.  Any longer of blade of your grass will need someone with a good blower to blow those blades of grass to be cut evenly and no lower than 3" as you mow.  In fact, if your grass is 6" that would really be too much to cut off at one time.

Using a weed wacker might work if you are able to use the lines to work like the rotary mower, sucking the blades of grass upwards before quickly cutting only an inch off the blades of grass.  Then using that blower, blow the clippings out and off your lawn onto your plant beds.  Not easy to do.

It will not kill your grass if you just go mow it and remove enough to get 3.5" in height.  One time, no biggie.  I reread your question and you say it was mowed last week at 3.5"...do it again.  Please bag clippings.  Clippings are great stuff but your lawn won't benefit!

Crucial are super super sharp mower blades.  What are you height adjustments on your mower?  I am so impressed with mowers finally being allowed adjustments of 3" not to mention 3.5 or 4.5!!  I LOVE the look of lawns like this and I am the only one I know that has done this on a regular basis until you!  Way cool!  Please mow again and send another picture of newly mowed!  At these lengths grass growth is supposed to slow waaaayyyy down.  If this is one week later after 3.5" mowing height...when did you fertilize and what was the formulation?

Tell us more, J.!  I'd love to promote this look but unless in shade this is tough to achieve but obviously you are achieving this!  Grass this height in the sun and fertilized needs vigilance.  So pretty!  So soft!  Right?  Yummmm.  And I want you to get a 'ruler' pull those grass blades up and take a picture!!  Please?  Amazing it grew this long in one week.  Sharpen your mower blades, use alcohol every time you sharpen or change out your blades, bag clippings.  Please give any detail possible.  I'd like to see this done more often but having a lawn at this height is ADVANCED lawn stuff.  You need to consider mowing twice per week, not once to allow your lawn almost this height.  As soon as those blades begin to fall over, mow your lawn.

Comment: I did say it was cool season mix of fescue and bluegrass.  There is no way to ID any grass from pictures, unless they took pictures of each type of grass, their seed heads as well as cross sections and their, what's it called...awl?  The 'skirt' that encloses the stem...arghhh.  Anyhoo, cool season grasses.

Comment: @pnuts stormy is absolutely right - identifying grasses is something of a specialist subject in botany and many species can only be differentiated using a hand lens and scalpel.

Comment: Hey, that part of my Botany ID course was not fun!!  The dang frozen flowers were far better.  Can you imagine mush with which to ID a plant using a big fat dichotomous key?  I love microscopes but headaches were very prevalent.  Grasses are incredible to ID.  Thanks, George!

Comment: I'm sure this is definitely a mix. I live in MA so it's cool season for sure. I just happened to notice this area of the grass is nice and soft so I wasn't sure if it was KBG or maybe a rye grass. The color on it from far away it also a bit deeper green which made me think it was KBG as well. I'd like to overseed more of it in the fall because I like it.

Comment: I will take another picture after I mow again at 3.5" - I think I just need to mow it twice a week at 3.5" - this picture is definitely about a week later, so its like 5"+ at this point.

Comment: Why do you say to bag the clippings? I thought its a good idea to mulch them?

Comment: I can't even imagine a mower that is able to chop the plant material fine enough to call it mulching.  They all say they are mulching mowers but knowing the beast called a lawn as well as I do I will never allow clippings to lay on the lawn.  Thatch is a big problem if you do not have the proper bacteria to decompose this newly dead material.  Great stuff for plant beds and your compost pile but don't allow clippings on your lawn.  It sounds like a great idea but it takes nitrogen to decompose these clippings so the nitrogen in those clippings is available for use by plants.